# Disable action in hideActionsets

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to disable an action alone  using  `IWorkbenchPage.hideActionSet` ? if it what should is pass a action id in the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this method is only used to hide a complete action set.